# How can I sum values of durations column when starttime and endtime is same day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Part of a big table is given below. I want to know how can I sum all durations whose starttime and end time is same day. Please help.

[image]

Comment: does it not matter if they are from different months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT startTime, SUM(duration) as sum
FROM myTable
WHERE startTime = endTime
GROUP BY startTime
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select sum(duration)
from table t
where startTime = endTime;
```